# Best way to substitute text

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have the following text in a file

```
/etc/pam.d/systemd-user|S.5....T.
/etc/bluetooth|not owned
/etc/pam.d/crond|S.5....T.
/etc/pam.d/crond|S.5....T.
/var/log/dmesg|.M.......
```

the text after the `|` will change to either all `.` or will have a mixture or all of the following `SM5DLUGT`

I would like to substitute it for something more human-readable
example

```
.M......=Mode differs includes permissions and file type
SM......=Filesize,Mode differs includes permissions and file type
..5.....=md5 sum differs
```

The break down of each `.` is below

```
S file Size differs
M Mode differs (includes permissions and file type)
5 MD5 sum differs
D Device major/minor number mismatch
L readLink(2) path mismatch
U User ownership differs
G Group ownership differs
T mTime differs
```

I was looking to doing something like the below in awk

```
awk '{sub(/S......./,"file size differs")}; {sub(/SM....../,"file size\
differs,mode differes includes permissions and file type")}; \
{sub(/.M....../,"Mode differes includes permissions and file type")}; \
{sub(/..5...../,"MD5 sum differes differs")}; \
{sub(/...D..../,"Devicemajor/minoir number mistmatch")}; \
{sub(/....L.../,"Readlink path mismatch")}; \
{sub(/.....U../,"User ownership differs")}; \
{sub(/......G./,"file size differs")}; {sub(/.......T/,"mTime differs")}; \
{print $0}' /system_files_protection.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you provide what have you already achieved? What is the exact problem?

Comment: What do you want to have as output?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are parsing the output of `rpm` in verify mode, so some minor adjustments have been made (though I am unsure about the "not owned" line). Support for handling "?" for a failed test *is not* included here though.

The main problems with your approach are that one should not (generally) try to incrementally process data as it is modified; and that "." in the strings you match is a regex wildcard character which can then match the modified data. e.g. `/.M......./` as a regex will match "`.M.......`", and "`Mode differs`", "`MD5 sum`" etc. (and more if `IGNORECASE` is not 0 in GNU awk.)

Another problem is the number of permutations, it's impractical to match them all programmatically.

This code works as follows:

- create an array of messages `desc[]`, indexed by `"XY"` where `X` is the character position and `Y` is the literal character
- transforms the index from "`XY`" to "`...Y.....`" where Y is in the Xth position (you could just do this yourself of course, but that's tedious and error prone¹)
- reads each input line, attempts to match each index pattern in turn, and accumulates the relevant message in `output[]`
- flattens `output[]` into a comma-separated list
- prints the result per-input line

In case you are unfamiliar, the construction `(expression) ? "true" : "false"` is used here to insert (or not) commas or plural trailing "s" if appropriate, saving `if/else` and duplication. `"........."` is a magic string, and 9 is a magic number (you might to change these if your `rpm` output really is old and lacks "P" as a 9th column).

The "`%.*s`" in `printf()` allows selecting variable length prefix of the `"........."` padding on each side. For position N (starting at 1), it outputs N-1 characters to prefix, the match part, then 9-N characters to suffix.

```
BEGIN {
    FS="|"

    desc["1S"]="file Size differs"
    desc["2M"]="Mode differs (includes permissions and file type)"
    desc["35"]="MD5 sum differs"
    desc["4D"]="Device major/minor number mismatch"
    desc["5L"]="readLink(2) path mismatch"
    desc["6U"]="User ownership differs"
    desc["7G"]="Group ownership differs"
    desc["8T"]="mTime differs"
    desc["9P"]="caPabilities differ"

    ## transform indexes: "4D" -> "...D....."  with "D" in the 4th column
    for (dd in desc) {
         match(dd,/([0-9]+)(.)/,bits)
         regex=sprintf("%.*s%s%.*s",bits[1]-1,".........",bits[2],
                                    9-bits[1],"........")
         sub(/ differs?/,"",desc[dd])
         desc[regex]=desc[dd]; delete desc[dd]
    }
}
{ 
     oo=0; out=""

     for (regex in desc) 
         if ($2 ~ regex) output[++oo]=desc[regex]

     for (ii=1; ii<=oo; ii++) 
         out=sprintf("%s%s%s",out, (ii>1)?", ":"", output[ii]);

     printf("%s|%s differ%sn",$1,out,(oo==1)?"s":"")
}
```

Such code is flexible enough to process many variations of flags like this.

If you needed to handle "?" in the input too, you could amend the regular expression code to generate a more complicated regular expression, e.g.  "`.(M|\?).......`" instead of just "`.M.......`"; and then handle this by inspecting the matches in the `for (regex in desc)` loop.

---

1. The first script bug I ever fixed was an awk script processing log files. It had a hard-coded array of month names for lookup, or rather an array *with one month name missing*. You'd be surprised how long it can take to spot that...